# Form data is not transmitted in razor pages

Tags: c#, .net, forms, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am writing a small project in razor pages and ran into the following problem.

I have a simple page

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model WarrantyModel

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Submit">
   <input type="email" name="email" vale="@Model.Email" disabled/>
   <input type="text" name="comment" />
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

My POST method:

```
public Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmitAsync()
{
   var IFormCollection form = Request.Form;
   // to do some action
}
```

A problem occurs when submitting form data. The field (mail) that I filled in dynamically (`@Model.Email`) is not transmitted. Only the comment field, entered manually, is transmitted. Maybe someone knows what this behavior is related to and how to get rid of it?

Comment: I'm assuming the "vale='@Model.Email" is a typo in your code sample and is actually 'value'...

Comment: @DavidW `@Model.Email` - it's field from model class. But I already figured it out, the `disabled` attribute interfered.

Comment: So is it solved or are you still having issue's ?

Comment: @Scircia, yes it is decided

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to access the each element from the form:

`var data=Request.Form["comment"]`

For more reference you can try out this link: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms

Comment: Note that the original poster commented: "I already figured it out, the `disabled` attribute interfered". I'm afraid this answer doesn't add much value.